# Building a ColumnStore index hogs system resources

Tags: sql-server, columnstore

I am experimenting with the columnstore and I am finding that while it is building the process hogs all the system resources. I have a table with 2.3 billion rows and while I build the columnstore on it all other queries come to a complete stand still. Is there a way to limit the amount of resources used by the columnstore build so that my other queries can continue to run. The other queries do not involve this table.

Comment: You should possibly add some findings (form logs, monitoring, etc.) that support that the columnstore build is the culprit.

Comment: I am using sp_Who2 active and the ColumnStore process and my other query are the only things running. Just as soon I kill the ColumnStore build the Other query runs right away. I have repeated this process several time and it is obvious that the columnstore build is the culprit.

Comment: I have also tried using Maxdop with various values and they don't seem to help.

Comment: Is the query that "comes to a complete stand still" trying to query against the same table where you're building the ColumnStore index?

Comment: The other queries do not involve this table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the index build in a [resource governor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx) group that limits the resources you want to give. Columnstore building is CPU and memory intensive. Resource governor should be your preferred way to throttle resources, no matter the scenario.

Comment: I am researching the resource governor now and this appears to be a tool that would help this situation. It also gives me some ideas on how to solve issues with user accessability during various times of the day.